# How to sort a list in descending order according to a map which is already sorted in descending order

Tags: groovy

I have a JSON array (list of maps) similar to:

```
def listOfMap = [[TESTCASE:1, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'PASS'],  
      [TESTCASE:2, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'FAIL'],  
      [TESTCASE:3, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'FAIL'],   
      [TESTCASE:4, METHOD:'TYPETEXT', RESULT:'FAIL']]
```

I am grouping by the METHOD names and collecting the FAILURE % of each method

```
def percentage (map){
     (map.FAIL ?: 0) / ((map.PASS ?: 0) + (map.FAIL ?: 0)) * 100
}

def result = listOfMap.groupBy{it.METHOD}
                      .collectEntries{[(it.key) : percentage(it.value.countBy{it.RESULT})]}
```

Now my output will be [CLICK : 66.6, TYPETEXT : 100]

To sort the above result in descending order of percentage,

```
def sortedResult = result.sort { a, b -> b.value <=> a.value }
```

Now my output will be [TYPETEXT : 100, CLICK : 66.6]

How can i get the FAIL count and PASS count of the METHOD linked to the above sorted order?

My output should be two separate lists (sorted in descending order of failure %)

```
passList  = [0, 1]     Note : [TYPETEXT passed 0 times, CLICK passed 1 time]
failList =  [1, 2]     Note : [TYPETEXT failed 1 time, CLICK failed 2 times]
```

Basically i am looking for this data to create a CSV report something like the below from the listofMap given:

[image: CSV Report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this (from the original post):

```
def listOfMap = [[TESTCASE:1, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'PASS'],  
      [TESTCASE:2, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'FAIL'],  
      [TESTCASE:3, METHOD:'CLICK', RESULT:'FAIL'],   
      [TESTCASE:4, METHOD:'TYPETEXT', RESULT:'FAIL']]
```

Consider using `Expando` so that `percentage` is a field, but also `passCount` and `failCount`:

```
def percentage(passCount, failCount) {
    failCount / (passCount + failCount) * 100
}

def result = listOfMap.groupBy{it.METHOD}.collectEntries{
                def rec = new Expando()
                def count = it.value.countBy{ it.RESULT } 

                rec."passCount" = count.'PASS' ?: 0
                rec."failCount" = count.'FAIL' ?: 0
                rec."percentage" = percentage(rec."passCount",
                                              rec."failCount")

                [(it.key) : rec]
             }

def sortedResult = result.sort { a, b -> 
                       b.value."percentage" <=> a.value."percentage" 
                   }
sortedResult.each { println it }
```

The output matches the basic schema desired for the CSV:

```
$ groovy Example.groovy 
TYPETEXT={failCount=1, percentage=100, passCount=0}
CLICK={failCount=2, percentage=66.6666666700, passCount=1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multi-grouping to make your life easier:

```
def listOfMap = [[TESTCASE: 1, METHOD: 'CLICK', RESULT: 'PASS'],
    [TESTCASE: 2, METHOD: 'CLICK', RESULT: 'FAIL'],
    [TESTCASE: 3, METHOD: 'CLICK', RESULT: 'FAIL'],
    [TESTCASE: 4, METHOD: 'TYPETEXT', RESULT: 'FAIL']]

def result = listOfMap.groupBy({ it.METHOD }, { it.RESULT })
                      .collectEntries { method, r ->
    def passCount = r.PASS?.size() ?: 0
    def failCount = r.FAIL?.size() ?: 0
    [method, [passCount: passCount, failCount: failCount, failPercentage: (failCount / (passCount + failCount) * 100.0)]]
}.sort { -it.value.failPercentage }
```

You can then do:

```
result.values().failCount
```

or

```
result.values().passCount
```

to get the numbers you require in the question.

It's best to never try and keep multiple separate lists in the same order, much easier to store all the data together, and extract it after sorting the whole thing